empty dSYM file detected, dSYM was created with an executable with no debug info
Im trying to automatically upload  Dsyms to crashlythics which was working earlier, now when i tried, i'm getting this warning

Also when i checked on firebase it shows Dsyms where missing

This is the run script added

Dsyms was uplaoding with this script previuosly, but now its not working
xcode version : 16.0
Flutter Version : 3.7.0
What i tried

Updating debug information info to Dwarf with dsym file for both target and pods

If this information is not enough please comment, will add more details

did you get any solution?

I had the same issue since updating to Xcode 16. There's more information here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/13543
I'd suggest to update your firebase dependencies to their latest version(s), which as of now, firebase_core is v3.7.0 which uses v11.4 of Firebase/Core on iOS.
Switch the 'Debug Dylib Support' in Xcode target Build settings to False.
Follow the latest Firebase guide for dSYM submission setup on the Firebase website, especially the run scripts section: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=flutter

You should check that if you're using Xcode 16:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79246834/4260691

I have fixed this issue by setting Enable Debug Dylib Support to No.
If it is already set to No, change it to Yes and build the project and then set it back to No and build the project again.


This actually silenced the warning but I still could not get the crash reflected on Crashlytics dashboard.

@YusufKamilAK, it does take some time to reflect on Crashlytics dashboard. Can you please check dashboard after an hour or more? Additionally, you can try to crash the app by calling .crash() on crashlytics instance. This way you might get report faster.

I tried also. Like about an hour ago I had a crush and still nothing happened. Still saying that app detected. I can't see any logs on firebase console also. On the other hand android side works perfectly. Is there any other configuration?

It's working..., thanks

@Handelika, are you still seeing the empty DSYM warning in the Xcode log, or the error warning disappeared but you are unable to view logs in Firebase?

@AbhishekGhimire The error gone but I couldn't get the crashlytics logs. Also firebase side said application detected but not getting dsym. All my 3 project has the same problem. I just build applications and all same result :(

Each build has a unique dSYM file. When you create a production build, you can find the dSYM file at ios/build/. This file is automatically uploaded during the build phase by a script (either the FlutterFire script or your own manual script). However, sometimes the script may fail, resulting in a warning about the missing dSYM file because it was not uploaded. Once the dSYM file is lost, you cannot re-upload it to Firebase, and the warning will persist indefinitely. To avoid this, save the dSYM file locally every time you create a build so that you can manually upload it to Firebase if needed

@AbhishekGhimire I accomplished with crashlytics.sendUnsentReports():) It is crazy. Thanks for your help =)
